# Collapse Expand UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I tried to expand/collapse an `UITableView` that is inside an `UIViewController`. I put the `UITableView` height constraint to zero and make the animation

```
func collapseExpandRoomSection() {
     isRoomCollapsed = !isRoomCollapsed
     tableHeightConstraint.constant = isRoomCollapsed ? 0.0 : totalTableHeight    
     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { 
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     }
 }
```

The collapse effect works fine but when I tried to expand the table all the cells are gone.

Thanks

Comment: paste code for expand here..

Comment: I'd guess that your `totalTableHeight` is not properly set. Have you checked that it's > 0 inside your `collapseExpandRoomSection()` method? Try to temporarily replace `totalTableHeight` with a constant value like 50.0 and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have updated the `constraint`, You should be doing it in this order I believe:

```
self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

As you have updated the constraint, therefore you should firstly update the set update constraints and set needs layout. Followed by the `layoutIfNeeded()` to have the change apply immediately.

As discussed briefly on the comments, the code is only applicable if you override the `updateConstraint`. Is not correct in answering the question above.

Comment: That's incorrect. Whenever you add, remove or modify constraints on a view the layout is automatically invalidated (`setNeedsLayout()`) and in the next layout cycle the frames will be automatically recomputed. Furthermore, you won't need to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` in 95% of the cases. It only needs to be called if you have overridden `updateConstraints()` in your implementation and you actually modify constraints in there based on some state variables of your view.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. I misunderstood what the documentation say I believe. Will not delete the answer but edit it to say is wrong.

Comment: You're not the first person to misunderstand the docs on these layout methods... ;)